# Is element order a guaranteed way of defining z-index?

Tags: html, css

I have some overlapping containers. By default, which one is on top is determined by the order in which the elements come in. Can I count on that to never change or should I explicitly define z-index for them?

Comment: Depends on how you are overlapping them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index),

> Boxes with the same stack level in a stacking context are stacked
>   back-to-front according to document tree order.

So yes, this is usually guaranteed.

However, note that in [Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting), `order` is used instead:

> Flex items paint exactly the same as inline blocks, except that
>   [`order`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-order)-modified document order is used in place of raw document
>   order

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set anything with `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`, it won't change